# ajax uploading control

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there any free ajax uploading control which can give black-screen on the page to prevent other user interaction while uploading? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [jQuery Ui Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), make it a modal popup and put your uploading buttons etc on the popup and it should just work fine!

Comment: That's cool, thanks you all! But what should I do if I want a progress bar on the dialog? It's best to be circuler progress bar.

Comment: in my example then the .progress class or id of however you get it in the css has a higher z-index compared to the overlay

Answer (score 0):

Just when you are calling the upload code add the following before it.

```
$('body').append('<div class="overlay"></div>');
```

and css like:

```
.overlay {
            background:black; 
            opacity:0.4; 
            filter:alpha(opacity=40); 
            width:100%; 
            height:100%; 
            position:absolute; 
            top:0; 
            left:0; 
            z-index:2000;
            }
```